# swf respondDecisionTaskCompleted call, response time degrade overtime

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk

We have a decided worker running and as the time goes we noticed the response time of the `respondDecisionTaskCompleted` call was getting slower and slower.

We tried using the same instance of the SWF client as well as creating a new instance of the client on every call, but we're still experiencing the same behavior: sometimes the response time can even go up to 3-5 minutes.

We suspect there is some kind of a leak because as we redeploy, the response time becomes fast and then decreases after a few hundred calls.

We are using JavaScript AWS SDK.

Any suggestion on what should we look into?

Comment: Hi, have you used the **Interval**  method to revoke the function multiple times, bcoz if that is the case, then I'm afraid as in flash it starts to slow down after sometime and that might be causing the delays in your response time. I would suggest you to use the **recursive function** instead of that.

Comment: without code, we can do nothing

Comment: As Sagar V pointed out, the absence of code makes identifying a solution impractical.  It could be a problem in any number of points.  Perhaps it is an inflating object that takes longer to traverse as the size increases.  Perhaps you have a memory leak, and the number of objects being created versus garbage collected is taking its toll.  Perhaps the response is awaiting other events to happen, at which point it has nothing to do with your SWF.

Comment: Should "decided worker" be "dedicated server"?